# NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSDictionaryM doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2807e6c40

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, release

I've been working on a React Native app utilizing React Native CLI and integrating Firebase for user authentication. The app operates seamlessly in debug mode on iOS with no reported issues.

However, when attempting to deploy the app through TestFlight or by switching the scheme to Release for running, I encounter an unexpected error:

> NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSDictionaryM doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2807e6c40

Screenshot of the exception in XCode

[image]

This error occurs at a specific point in the app flow i.e. widgets screen which uses this library **react-native-drag-sort**

Could someone please provide insights into why this error might occur specifically during TestFlight deployment and how to resolve the NSInvalidArgumentException related to doubleValue?

I've already:

- Confirmed that the app works as expected in debug mode.
- Changed the optimisation for Release to none.

Here is the Widget Screen Code:-

```
import React, {createRef, useState, useEffect, useRef} from 

import React, {createRef, useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Animated,
  Vibration,
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import {useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {calendarWidgetList} from '../../constants/general';
import {AnySizeDragSortableView} from 'react-native-drag-sort';
import LoadingIndicator from '../loadingindicator/LoadingIndicator';
import {
  deleteWidget,
  fetchWidgets,
  getWidgetsFromFirebase,
  uploadWidgetsToFirebase,
} from '../../utils/function';
import Images from '../../constants/images';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {COLORS} from '../../constants';

export default Draggable = ({userId, addedWidgets}) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const sortableViewRef = useRef();
  const [widgets, setWidgets] = useState(addedWidgets);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [movedKey, setMovedKey] = useState(null);
  const [jiggleAnimation] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
  const [disableScroll, setDisableScroll] = useState(false);
  const startJiggleAnimation = () => {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(jiggleAnimation, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 150,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
        Animated.timing(jiggleAnimation, {
          toValue: -1,
          duration: 150,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
        Animated.timing(jiggleAnimation, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 150,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
      ]),
    ).start();
  };

  const stopJiggleAnimation = () => {
    jiggleAnimation.stopAnimation();
    jiggleAnimation.setValue(0);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      stopJiggleAnimation();
    };
  }, []);

  const handleLongPress = (item, index) => {
    setMovedKey(item.id);
    sortableViewRef.current.startTouch(item, index);
    Vibration.vibrate(50);
    startJiggleAnimation();
    setDisableScroll(true);
  };

  const handleDragEnd = () => {
    setMovedKey(null);
    setDisableScroll(false);
    updateOrder();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setWidgets(addedWidgets);
  }, [addedWidgets]);

  const updateOrder = () => {
    let count = 0;
    widgets.forEach(i => {
      addedWidgets.forEach(j => {
        if (j.id === i.id) {
          j.id = count;

          count++;
        }
      });
    });

    uploadWidgetsToFirebase(userId, widgets);
  };

  const handleDeleteWidget = async itemId => {
    const updatedWidgets = widgets.filter(item => item.id !== itemId);

    setWidgets(updatedWidgets);
    sortableViewRef.current.onPressOut();

    deleteWidget(userId, itemId);
  };

  // useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    const fetchWidgets = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const updatedWidgetsAfterDeletion = await getWidgetsFromFirebase(userId);
      setWidgets(updatedWidgetsAfterDeletion);
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchWidgets();
  }, [userId]),
    // );

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!isLoading) {
        sortableViewRef.current?.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});
      }
    }, [isLoading]);

  const renderItem = (item, index, isMoved) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={1}
        // onPressOut={handlePressOut}
        onLongPress={() => handleLongPress(item, index)}
        // onPressOut={() => sortableViewRef.current.onPressOut()}
      >
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            {
              position: 'relative',
              paddingTop: 0, //Change gap between widgets
            },
            isMoved && {
              transform: [
                {
                  rotate: jiggleAnimation.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                    outputRange: ['1deg', '-1deg'],
                  }),
                },
              ],
            },
          ]}>
          <View
            style={[
              styles.widget,
              {
                width: item.width,
                height: item.height, //Change gap between widgets if paddingTop = 0 is not enough
              },
            ]}>
            {isMoved ? (
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    zIndex: 10,
                  }}
                  onPress={() => {
                    handleDeleteWidget(item.id);
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={Images['remove_widget']}
                    style={{
                      opacity: 0.7,
                      height: 23,
                      width: 23,
                      position: 'absolute',
                      top: -5,
                      left: -5,
                    }}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                {item.component}
              </View>
            ) : (
              <View>{item.component}</View>
            )}
          </View>
        </Animated.View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return isLoading ? (
    <LoadingIndicator />
  ) : (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView
        // onScroll={sortableViewRef.current?.onPressOut()}
        scrollEnabled={!disableScroll}
        contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>
        <AnySizeDragSortableView           //This line is the point where the error starts
          ref={sortableViewRef}
          dataSource={widgets}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          onDataChange={(data, callback) => {
            setWidgets(data);
            callback();
          }}
          movedWrapStyle={styles.widgetMoved}
          onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking on "Open in Project.." and finding out where exactly in the code does it crash?

Comment: Yes I did, its 
#5 0x1009bee0c in __41-[RCTModuleMethod processMethodSignature]_block_invoke_11 at /Users/spencer/CampConnection/CampConnection_MA/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm:306

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that's in `RTCModuleMethod.mm` and specifically line `306` and what it executes..

Comment: It's hard to tell, but at some point, I guess that the code expects a `NSNumber` (or maybe `NSString`) and it has a `NS(Mutable)Dictionary` instead, hence the error. If you could reproduce, try to check the value in the debugger and see why...

Comment: I figured out where the error was, and edited the information accordingly @PierreJanineh

Comment: Where exactly is the error? comment the line maybe? According to what I can understand, the issue might be in one of the functions in `../../utils/function`

Comment: Yea if I comment it, it works, but thats an important part of the code (basically a library AnySizeDragSortableView component) as it is used to display in app widgets which can be dragged and dropped.

Comment: It's unclear, what's your current fix then, or the culprit?

Comment: Current fix is I used another library (which is a temporary solution, looking forward to getting this fixed). 
The culprit is the AnySizeDragSortableView component line. I have added a comment beside it as well.

Comment: I don't "speak" ReactNative, but check that every parameter is of correct type. If I refer to this https://github.com/mochixuan/react-native-drag-sort, is `styles.widgetMove` a `StyleProp`, etc. There might be one value that isn't of the correct type, hence the error.